# Apache Spark collect Exceptions or messages, which describe unexpected behavior

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am developing an application with Apache Spark and I need an ability to collect custom exceptions or messages and then send them via email.

Currently I am using `CollectionAccumulator[String]` but everywhere I must provide implicitly or explicitly this accumulator or sparkContext.

I am pretty sure there must be something like a global object holder, which could be used in such way: `GlobalExceptionAccumulator.accumulate(e)`, or someone used something similar or even better solution for this. Maybe custom wrapper for this accumulator.

Here is how it developed for now:

```
implicit val acc = spark.sparkContext.collectionAccumulator[String]("Failed.")
        ...
object Mappings {
        ...      
    def valueOf(name: String)(implicit accumulator: CollectionAccumulator[String]): String = {
           Try(vals(name)) match {
              case Success(value) => value
                  case Failure(e) =>
                    accumulator.add(s"No value defined for '$name'")
                    ""
           }
    }
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use LogStash with ElasticSearch and Kibana instead. So our log messages get posted into log server. Kibana provides visualization. ElasticSearch provides full text search.